# Trouble in using Business hours methods to compare business hours with specific number of hours in apex trigger

Tags: email2case, case-object, businesshours

I'm trying to compare number of business hours with number of hours (bh<48)
I have gone through few methods and tried the below method to get number of hours(difference between startdate and enddate :

```
diff(BusinessHours.id, startdate, Datetime.now())<48)
```

But I'm constantly getting the same error for all the methods :
**"Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [BusinessHours].diff(Schema.SObjectField, Datetime, Datetime)"**

I dont understand this error as usage of methods are referred here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_businesshours.htm

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!
TIA

Comment: The error is expected because you are passing  **diff(BusinessHours.id, startdate, Datetime.now())** BusinessHours.Id is of type SObject.SObjectField. You should pass the id of  instance of businesshour

Comment: @EhsanMahmoudi I rectified that long back , I did create an instance via SOQL query and passed in diff() method. Thank you ! :)

Comment: What is the API version of the class that you are working on? It might be too old

Comment: @EhsanMahmoudi, Its 34.0 its the latest one, BTW its a trigger and I got it working now ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to do something like this first: (from your link)

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
```

Then use that id as the first parameter in the method:

```
diff(bh.id, startdate, Datetime.now())<48)
```

You were getting an error message because you were using the name of the type of parameter that you needed to put into the function instead of using a value of that type.

---

I got this to run:

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
Datetime startdate = Datetime.newInstance(2013, 5, 28, 1, 6, 8);
long l = BusinessHours.diff(bh.id,startdate,system.now());
system.debug(l);
```

---

I this also worked for me:

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
Case c = [SELECT ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE ClosedDate != NULL LIMIT 1];

DateTime startdate = c.ClosedDate;
DateTime systemnow = system.now();

long startl = startdate.getTime();
long nowl   = systemnow.getTime();
long diffl  = BusinessHours.diff(bh.id,startdate,systemnow);

system.debug('startl: ' + startl);
system.debug('nowl: '   + nowl);
system.debug('nowl - startl: ' + (nowl - startl));
system.debug('diffl: '  + diffl);

system.assertEquals(nowl-startl,diffl);
```

---

This also works:

```
Trigger Test_Business_hours_Trigger on EmailMessage (after insert) {
    BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
    list<Id> RelatedCaseIds = new list<Id>();
    for(EmailMessage em : Trigger.New){
        RelatedCaseIds.add(em.ParentId);
    }
    list<Case> CasesToUpdate = new list<Case>();
    for(Case c : [SELECT Id, ClosedDate FROM Case WHERE Id IN :RelatedCaseIds AND ClosedDate != NULL]){
        if(BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id,c.ClosedDate,system.now()) < 172800000){
            c.Status = 'Working';
            CasesToUpdate.add(c);
        }
    }
    update CasesToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Martin, I have written query already ! Still am getting the error! All the needful is done ,as per the info provided in the link.

Comment: @SFDCWolf The same error?

Comment: Yep! "Method does not exist" for any method mentioned in the link ! I strongly feel there is something else has to be done, I have my business hours defined in the org already !

Comment: @SFDCWolf it could be that you were missing the `BusinessHours.` before the diff() method.

Comment: @SFDCWolf Also, make sure you convert 48 from hours to milliseconds.

Comment: I have not missed bussiness hours.diff(), Also I have converted 48 hours to milliseconds, the above method i.e,                                                         BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
Datetime startdate = Datetime.newInstance(2013, 5, 28, 1, 6, 8);
 it runs, but doesn't work for  me , here the start date is supposed to be the date time field(Closed date) from case object , any idea how to use here ?

Comment: @SFDCWolf You might have to be more specific on how it doesn't work. I've updated my answer with with a working example that uses the Case ClosedDate field instead of constructing a new DateTime.

Comment: I got the code to run now and I hope its working now, yet to test its functionality to determine the method is correct, it is associated with case email repllies, so still testing the scenario ! Thanks Martin! :) Creating an instance of start date and end date solved the error BTW !

Comment: @SFDCWolf nice! glad to help.

Comment: Hi Martin, I dont understand why it doesnt work, I'm getting the l value in system.debug() but the field update isn't working 'trigger , Can you try this in your dev org ?

Comment: Code posted as answer above!

Comment: One of the problems is that you are querying one particular case instead of acting on all of the records in a trigger context variable, i.e. `trigger.new`.

Comment: For(emailmessage em :trigger.new) , this is what you are talking about @martin ?

Comment: @SFDCWolf Yes. If you want the trigger to perform some action based on the records that are currently the target of some DML operation, you should use the trigger context variables.

Comment: I did include trigger.new as in for loop as mentioned, I'm still digging where is it going wrong !

Comment: @SFDCWolf What do you want the trigger to do?

Comment: The requirement is very clear @martin , Once a case is closed and if customer replies back via mail with in 48 hours of closed date then the status has to be updated to working again.

Comment: @SFDCWolf I've updated my answer.

Comment: Here, @martin, in your updated answer is what I have already implemented, but here the most important thing about this requirement is to consider org defined business hours and that's the reason I had to go for business hour methods.

Comment: @SFDCWolf so it's 48 business hours then. right?

Comment: @SFDCWolf by the way, the default business hours are 24/7. Do you have the business hours set correctly in your test environment?

Comment: Here @martin ,we have our business hours defined by us lets say 9am to 5 pm and weekends off ! So that's how we have defined and yes they are defined correctly. Also, in the present code, a value is being passed to variable , I have checked debug logs also but still the requirement is not met.

Comment: by the way, did you try the code with business hours in your dev org ? status is updated to working?

Comment: @SFDCWolf I had to make a few changes, but yes, it works.